# in _asarray_tuplesafe result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]

Tags: python, pandas

my function is like this :

```
def computer_daily_returns(df):
    daily_returns = df.copy()
    daily_returns[1:] = (df[1:] / df[:-1].values) - 1
    **daily_returns.ix[0, :] = 0**
    return daily_returns
```

and will generate a df like below:

```
                GOOG      AAPL       GLD       XOM
2010-01-04  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2010-01-05 -0.004404  0.001689 -0.000911  0.003873
2010-01-06 -0.025209 -0.015881  0.016500  0.008642
2010-01-07 -0.023280 -0.001857 -0.006188 -0.003213
2010-01-08  0.013331  0.006629  0.004963 -0.003991
2010-01-11 -0.001512 -0.008812  0.013289  0.011250
2010-01-12 -0.017684 -0.011376 -0.020913 -0.005029
```

when i was trying to use

```
allocs = spo.minimize(sharpe_ratio, guess_allocs, args=(normed,) bla bla bla..
```

it gave me

```
ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")
```

`sharpe_ratio` is a function and contains `computer_daily_returns` function.
after i delete `daily_returns.ix[0, :] = 0` everything is working fine ..

Comment: sry the error is in _minimize_slsqp raise ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What are you trying to do?